# MySQL Querying through Metadata-like Table

Tags: php, mysql

How do I more easily search through table data where the table structure is

```
id | post_id | meta_key | meta_value
```

For example, if I know a few of the meta_values I am interested in and I know their corresponding meta_key, how do I write a query for it?

Suppose there are 5 row entries like for the same member like

```
id | post_id | meta_key | meta_value
1  |   22    | fname     | Bobby
2  |   22    | lname     | Bobertson
3  |   22    | age       | 50
4  |   22    | member_id | 99
```

And I want to get `fname, lname` where `member_id` = 99 ?

I know exactly how to write many forloops to do this, but I figure this table design pattern is common so there must be a trivial way to get data from it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, in case for each `post_id` there will be only one `member_id` you can use the following query:

```
select meta_value 
  from tbl 
  where meta_key in ('fname', 'lname') 
    and post_id in (select post_id 
                      from tbl 
                     where meta_key='member_id' 
                       and meta_value=99);
```

Comment: How will I know which is `fname` and which is `lname`

Comment: No - if you do `in ('fname','lname')` then I don't know which was which.

Comment: Just tested the query `select meta_key, meta_value from tbl where meta_key in ('fname', 'lname') and post_id in (select post_id from tbl where meta_key='member_id' and meta_value=99);` it returns two rows with two values in each: `fname=Bobby` and `lname=Bobertson`

Comment: It is not possible.. It is only choose `meta_value`, so the issue is that an array of` `['Bobby','Boberston']` is returned. It is not known by the program which is `fname` or `lname`

Comment: You can select two arrays separately or in case priority of values is always the same in database just use the first value as fname and second as lname.